# Microsoft Bot Authentication for multiple customers and multi tenants

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service

I need an authentication service. I need the same code for multiple customers and tenants. Also, is there any way by which I can register a single app in Azure while signing in for multiple customers/tenants?

Answer (score 1):

A bot doesn't care WHO your customers are, only that the connection string to the Azure app registration that is holding your auth service is valid. You can easily register a single app in Azure for multiple customers/tenants.

I recommend first starting with 'adding auth to my bot' doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) (and if it moves, I found that by judicious use of google).

Specifically, what you're looking for is first this:

[image: OAuth preliminary selection screen]

And then later, when you're setting up your connection string, you can either narrow down the service provider here, or create one of your own using 'Generic Oauth'..[image: Connection string settings page]

Comment: I have seen this option . But for authentication to bot services for multiple customers we have different logins urls how can we do this . If our company having 10 customers we need to create 10 connection strings in which we provide the login url and redirect url