# Microsoft Teams Manifest: can contentBotId be of different tenant

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

I am trying to use contentBotId (Azure bot ID) in my MS Teams manifest file.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/schema/manifest-schema-dev-preview
[image]
When it is from same tenant that of MS teams domain (xyz.com) then its working and loading the data

But when its from different tenant, then MS Teams is not loading anything

```
{errorCode: 0, message: "<BadArgument>Unknown bot"}
```

Is there any restriction on this?

Comment: Could you please confirm if your application is registered as multi-tenant or single tenant? https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQgvY.png

Comment: its is multi-tenant

Answer (score 1):

Before creating the MS bot, using ML Studio, create multi-tenant bot for perfect App registration.

Follow the procedure to create the bot and register the application.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

By mentioning all the required. Check the manifest file for the required ContentBotId. Test the URL after app registration into multi-Tenant.

If still the error occurs. We need to setup the connection settings under configurations.

[image]

[image]

By adding Oauth connection settings we will get some kind of authentication for different clients for the same authentication URL (website URL).

Comment: Thanks for sharing the steps. How to test the url  (last line in the answer)?

Comment: Followed all the steps, but still getting Unknow Bot error when opening in MS Teams. are you able to run it in your MS Teams?

Comment: The URL is the website URL. Currently the service which was created was not available from my side. But the same procedure can be used to work on this. The same procedure regarding the similar work was success with the same steps.

Comment: It working fine when azure resources and MS Teams are in same tenant, but its throwing error when azure resources are in different tenant even multi tenant is enabled

Comment: Can you please check with your subscription. Whether there are dependencies from your subscription.

Comment: Updating the answer with two more screens and also sharing one doc linke for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59137244/microsoft-bot-authentication-for-multiple-customers-and-multi-tenants

This seems to be the connection settings problem from client side and also with the authentication URL (The website URL)

Answer (score 0):

Able to resolve the issue.

*Yes it can be from different tenant.*

when we use existing AAD instead of creating from Azure bot template, this issue occurs. Seems like MS Teams is not able to find this AAD/ or Bot Handle.

**Root Cause (Might be)**: Manually created AAD have email address of user who have created this in *Owners* section (screenshot 1), while AAD created from Azure bot template have "Bot Framework Dev Portal" user (Screenshot 2).
And I am unable to add this user by searching.

**Screnshot 1**
[image: Screenshot1- Manfully created AAD]

**Screenshot2**
[image: Screenshot2]